# Not receiving network callbacks from livechat when my App is in background. Only on android on Ios it works fine

Tags: react-native

I have a chatting app and i am using livechat sdk to communicate between agent and client.When a chat is started {On chat started} callback is not received by the android app when its in background however its being received when its in foreground and  its being received on the Ios app when its in background and foreground both.Is there anyway to capture the callback from livechat in background on android? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Try adding some more information to your question, the more information you give the better it is for other users to be able to help you. Ask yourself a few questions and write these down, "What have you tried?", "What was the output?", "What was the expected output?". Provide code examples, allowing others to review your code may reveal some errors. Two sets of eyes are better than one!

Comment: Are you using a native android sdk?

Comment: No i am using react native sdk